# LT Spice measuring combined voltage

Tags: ltspice

I am trying to measure the combined output voltage from this entire circuit, but I can only measure the combined current [ I(V1) ] and the voltages at each resisters. The combined output voltage should be about 0 db.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can make traces of arbitrary functions of voltages and currents. So you can make one trace show V(n002)+V(n004)+V(n005).

Comment: How would I do that in the form of a graph?

Answer (score 2):

Right click on one of the labels at the top of your graph. It will give you a prompt for color, cursor settings, and, importantly, "Enter an algebraic expression to plot". Simply enter in your sum there to get it to plot the summed voltage.